# How to mask a UILabel in iOS - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, masking

I want to sub-class a UIView and place four UILabels over top one another ; top label will be the MASK, 2nd label will be a normal label with text, the 3rd label is a label with solid  background with no text.  the bottom label will the same as the top 2nd label with a different color font. when i sent the width of the third label it will cover up the bottom label showing a partial view of the text.  I want to have the 2nd text be one color while the uncoverd bottom label display another color font.

Is this possibe? If someone can explain how to mask in objective-C that will help too.

I trying to build a UIView that acts like a progress bar, as the bar fill to 60%, I want to top text to show in white font color, when the bottom text shows in a different color.

Comment: I kind of having it working by using the UILineBreakModeClip and laying the labels on top of each other. But the Clip seems to drop the last letter; I thought it was suppose to clip at where the rect ends. I want to render half of a "W"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with two UILabels, one on the bottom, and one embedded in another view on top.

```
UILabel *bottomLabel = ...;
[self.view addSubview:bottomLabel];

UIView *topContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bottomLabel.frame];
topContainer.clipsToBounds = YES;
topContainer.opaque = NO;
topContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UILabel *topLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bottomLabel.frame.size.width, bottomLabel.frame.size.height)];
topLabel.text = bottomLabel.text;
topLabel.opaque = NO;
topLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[topContainer addSubview:topLabel];
[self.view addSubview:topContainer];
```

Then, when you want to change the progress, you'd set the width of `topContainer`.  This should clip `topLabel`.

Comment: Will this allow partial character rendering? The goal is to make sure that if the progress bar is in between a character thent he character should show two colors

Comment: Yes. This should work because you'll be resizing the parent UIView instead of the UILabel.

Comment: Works like I want it to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using four UILabels, why not subclass UILabel and draw it yourself in the `drawRect:` method? It would look something like:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Set the mask
    CGContextClipToMask(context, self.bounds, /* mask image */);

    // Draw the text in a different font
    [self.text drawInRect:rect withFont:/* alternate font */];

    // Draw a solid background
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, ...);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    // Draw the text normally
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

You could make the masking image and the alternate font properties of your subclass, for convenience.

Comment: Will this allow partial character rendering? The goal is to make sure that if the progress bar is in between a character thent he character should show two colors.

Comment: You probably want to use self.bounds in CGContextClipToMask, not self.frame.