# Can't make UILabel clip

Tags: ios

I've sized my string to maximize height fit (1 line) so that any excessive width is cutoff (as in mid-glyph) which lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip should do. Instead text seems to truncate (?) by drawing only full characters that fit (not expected or desired). Basically:

```
[label setNumberOfLines:1];
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:64.0f];
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeClip;
[label setText:@"ABCDEIIIIII"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [related, more complicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009461/how-to-mask-a-uilabel-in-ios-objective-c) lays out a solution to this: create a label with a large width and add it to a UIView of your desired width. (Then add the UIView to your app.) Setting the clipsToBounds property of the UIView will give you the mid-glyph clipping you want.

Explanation: Let's say you want a label to cut off at 100px. Set the UILabel to a width of 200 and it will happily render the 100 pixels you want. Whether it truncates at full letters at 200, you don't care. You add this label to a UIView of 100px with clipsToBounds set, and it will show you only the desired 100px of the label and cut it off mid-glyph after that.

Adapted from the other post, to illustrate:

```
UIView *topContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
topContainer.clipsToBounds = YES;
topContainer.opaque = NO;
topContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UILabel *topLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50)];
[topLabel setText:@"ABCDEIIIIII"];
topLabel.opaque = NO;

[topContainer addSubview:topLabel];
[self.view addSubview:topContainer];
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use:

```
label.clipsToBounds = YES;
label.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

to get the effect you want.